# Combining two columns using shared values in first column

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to adjust the formatting of a data set. My current set looks like this, in two columns. The first column is a "cluster" and the second column "name" contains values within each cluster:

```
Cluster     Name
A           1
A           2
A           3
B           4
B           5
C           2
C           6
C           7
```

And I'd like a list that is, one column wherein all the values from column 2 are listed under the associated cluster from column 1 in a single column:

```
Cluster A
1
2
3
Cluster B
4
5
Cluster C
2
6
7
```

I've been trying in R and Excel with no luck for the last few hours. Any ideas?

Comment: Can the values repeat e.g.  1 and then another 1? Is this illustrative data and actually there can be many more rows?

Comment: Yes, the values can repeat and many belong to multiple Clusters. The file I have now is 26,000+ rows.

Comment: `split(df["Name"], paste0("Cluster_", df$Cluster))`

Answer (score 0):

Using a trick with `tidyr::nest` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(Cluster = paste0("Cluster_",Cluster)) %>% nest(Name) %>% t %>% unlist %>% as.data.frame
# .
# 1  Cluster_A
# 2          1
# 3          2
# 4          3
# 5  Cluster_B
# 6          4
# 7          5
# 8  Cluster_C
# 9          2
# 10         6
# 11         7
```